# Release Management Document

Tags: web-deployment, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management

It may be a simple question but I need some direction or idea on the below,

I'm new to deployment process and I started the deployment like deploying the code changes (asp.net + sql server) to various environment (QA, UAT and Staging). so far, we didn't have any documents but I heard that all these will be documented in Release Management Document. So, can you please share me any template for release management and also the topics need to be covered in the document. If you can share me then it will be great help for me.

If the term used is wrong please correct me. so, they expectation is need to prepare a document which talks about the release so can you please share me a template or topics need to be covered?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding SQL Server deployment, if you are using database project, you can deploy your database using DACPACs through [Azure SQL Database Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeployment) or [Deploy SQL Dacpac Deployment Group](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup) tasks.

More information, you can refer to [Build your SQL server database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-dacpac).

Regarding deploy ASP.NET app, you can deploy it through Azure App Service or IIS Website Deployment tasks.

More information, you can refer to: [Build your ASP.NET 4 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4?tabs=vsts).

On the other hand, there are various environments, so you can create multiple environments in Release for different environments. More information about VSTS release, you can refer to: [What is Release Management?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/what-is-release-management)

Comment: thank you. I'm able to deploy the application and db changes to respective environments but the expectation is a document named as Release Management Document. I'm not sure, what are topics need to be covered in that document. any inputs on that will be more helpful

Comment: The article of "What is Release Management?" is the official article. I'd suggest that you ask specific question in a thread.